# MVVM: Binding Convertors with Strongly Typed DataContext

Tags: mvvm, binding, datacontext, converters, ivalueconverter

I am in a great need of an idea;

This is what bothers me:

I have one View, named 'DropDownView '
This is how I use it:

```
<control:DropDownView  DataContext="{Binding StronglyTypedViewModel}"/>
```

Meaning, that in the parent page ViewModel, I have a property of type: `StronglyTypedViewModel<T>`

Now, when view is presented, this all works perfectly as I expect;

However, these few lines from the DropDownView are with troubling behavior:

```
<ctrl:CustomDropDown x:Name="cc"
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding ControlData}"
                                   ItemTemplate="{Binding ControlItemTemplate}"
                                   SelectedItem="{Binding ControlSelectedItem, ConverterParameter={Binding ControlData}, Converter={Binding}, Mode=TwoWay}"
...
```

With the SelectedItem Convertor property set, I get runtime exception: Error in binding...
Without it, I can see the dropdown values populated as expected (custom ItemTemplate is binded), but, presented as `object.ToString()`!

I have strongly typed ViewModel, meaning I should have strongly typed Converter, which is declared in the ViewModel, as:

```
public class SMOEntityProcessingViewModel<T> : CustomViewModelBase, IValueConverter
...
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
```

But, since I don't know the type of the ViewModel at compile time, I cannot add a StaticResource for the ViewModel, that could be used for the Convertor...

Any help is appreciated...
Thanks

**@devdigital**

```
ObservableCollection<T> ControlData;
object ControlSelectedItem;
ControlItemTemplate = Helpers.XAML.Methods.GenerateDataTemplate("{Binding Path=" + _propertyToShow + "}");
---------generating this in VM constructor, _propertyToShow depends on the T
```

i.e.

```
"<DataTemplate ");
"xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/"
"2006/xaml/presentation' "
"xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' >"
"<TextBlock Text='" + _propertyToShow + "' />"
"</DataTemplate>"
```

I don't know how to create the Converter yet, so that is still in progress...

Please let me know if you need further details, or maybe I could send some small demo on mail...
Thanks a lot for the interest...

Answer (score 0):

Your view model should only be responsible for the presentation logic of the associated view.  Separate out the converter code into a new type, and then you can add this as a resource where appropriate.  Also, assuming your CustomDropDown type derives from ItemsControl, you can use the DisplayMemberPath property to set which property of the underlying databound object is used in the display, or you can set the ItemTemplate property if you need more formatting control.

Comment: The base control is AutoCompleteBox; 
If ValueMemberPath is binded->runtime ex.; 
If ValueMemberBinding instead->app freezes;
The separated Converter should somehow know what is the incoming Type and which Property to convert...Should I maybe consider passing parameters (dependencyproperty) to DropDownView and bind them in Converter?

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing some more code.  What are the types for ControlData and ControlSelectedItem, and what does ControlItemTemplate look like?  If you create a separate converter and post the full updated code that would be helpful.